# Use of ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have SQL Server 2008 installed on my machine and also Reporting Services Configuration Manager. When I connect to SQL Server, I found two databases already there.

- ReportServer
- ReportServerTempDB

I know `ReportServer` is to store reports, data sources, snapshots, subscriptions, etc. But what is `ReportServerTempDB` for? Why is it created? Is that necessary (for our use)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the documentaion on [report server database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156016(v=sql.100).aspx)

The databases are created together and bound by name. By default, the database names are `reportserver` and `reportservertempdb`, respectively.

> Report Server Temporary Database
>
> Each report server database uses a related temporary database to store
>   session and execution data, cached reports, and work tables that are
>   generated by the report server. Reporting Services does not re-create
>   the temporary database if it is missing, nor does it repair missing or
>   modified tables. Although the temporary database does not contain
>   persistent data, you should back up a copy of the database anyway so
>   that you can avoid having to re-create it as part of a failure
>   recovery operation. If you back up the temporary database and
>   subsequently restore it, you should delete the contents. Generally, it
>   is safe to delete the contents of the temporary database at any time.
>   However, you must restart the Report Server Windows service after you
>   delete the contents. If you delete the temporary database, you can
>   create a new database, and then run the Catalogtempdb.sql script to
>   add the table structure. The temporary database must have the same
>   root name as the primary report server database.